# Refresh entities on database changes

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have an application used by many users at the same time.
I use Entity Framework to communicate with a PostgreSQL database running on a server.
The problem is when an user does an insert on the database, the other users will not see the change.

How can I refresh entities when a change is done on the database automatically?

Thanks

Comment: What's your front end? EF won't provide anything direct, but you could combine it with SignalR etc. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/05/21/datatable-using-signalr-angularjs-entityframework.aspx

Comment: Isn't SignalR is for web dev ? My app is a WinForms application

Comment: If you want to fill your refrigerator with milk it will not fill automatically if the milk arrives in market. You should go to market, bye milk and bring it to refrigerator... you can go to market every 5 minutes for instance to check if there is new bottle of milk and bring it to your refrigerator

Comment: Yes obviously but how do I implement that?

Comment: You can start the timer and update the grid every 5 minutes...

Comment: Great idea but that block my program during 2 secs every time I refresh the grid.

Comment: You could make use of a "Refresh Button" or a Background Worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in EF to do any kind of push notification from the DB.

However that doesn't mean you cant have real-time updates in your UI. Your database is simply a storage bucket, what you will want to do is to send out a notification when you write to your database.

If you are working with a web app something like signalR is good, Below is a little psudocode on how you might do that

```
context.Things.Add(newThing);
context.SaveChanges();

hubContext.Clients.All().newThingAdded(newThing);
```

There are many different types of notification techniques, and it depends a lot on the application you are writing which you should use.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers, I consider this question resolved.
I'll use a background worker to refresh some controls of my UI.
I think an auto-updater system will be too long to implement and my project comes to the deadline.